# PHP execution on monday morning for all users with different timezones via CRON

Tags: php, cron, timezone, execution

**What to accomplish:**

I want to export the user's activity (from the previous week) every monday morning between 4 and 5 am respecting the user's local timezone.

**Issue:**

Timezones..

**Situation:**

I'm running a PHP web service with the timezone set to UTC for the script and MySQL database. So all timestamps in the system are set to UTC and the user's timezone is stored with their account information.

I have a CRON scheduled to run and call the script every hour at the 30 minute mark.

Now the step I'm "stuck" at is on the part on how to determine if there are users in the system with a timezone set where it is currently between 04 and 05 am on a monday (when it's 19:30 UTC time for the server for example).

**Current solution:**

Thanks to @deceze in the comments for this suggestion!

(which seems to be an efficient way or at least the most logical way, which I completely skipped for some reason)

Do the timezone conversion on database level to filter the users.

```
WHERE 
   DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', users.raw_offset), "%w%H") = '104'
```

**Previous solution:**

Fetch all the active users, iterate them, create a new \DateTime with the timezone that is specified by the user, do an "if monday between 4-5 am" check, if so, execute the script for that user and continue with the next user. But this seems really inefficient if we would talk about thousands of users or something?

```
    $users = (new Models\User) -> getActiveUsers();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $localTimeUser = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone($user -> getTimezone()));
        if ($localTimeUser -> format('NH') === '104') {
            // execute
        }
    }
```

I could also "reverse" the determination by doing something like "in which timezone is it currently monday morning and get me the users with that timezone" but I haven't figured out the best way to check for that yet.

This is the first situation where I'm having trouble with timezones and I'm having a really hard time on figuring out the most efficient way to do something like this.

Is there a really straightforward solution that I'm currently missing or is checking thousands of user's timezones the only doable way?

**Subnote:**

The value `104` I compare with is just the easiest way I thought of, to have one value that indicates the day and the hour (1 = monday, 04 = 04:00 - 04:59 am) instead of checking between values etc.

Comment: Depending on your database, you may be able to do a query like `WHERE NOW(user.timezone) BETWEEN 4 AND 5` (very pseudocode)…

Comment: Welp.. That is a solution I haven't thought about! To filter them on database level yeah, seems like the most efficient way (and the most logical one)!